Daily Balance Prediction Using LSTM & ARIMA
I have the daily transaction history of a person from 1/1/2022 to 6/24/2024 in a csv file. The data is divided into train (1/1/2022 to 5/25/2024) and test (remaining). The data is given as :



Date
DebitAmount
CreditAmount
Balance




1/1/2022
1831
270
-1561


1/2/2022
2635
1047
-1588


1/3/2022
564
188
-376


1/4/2022
2325
1958
-367


1/5/2022
544
2122
1578


1/6/2022
2134
1839
-295


1/7/2022
2096
1624
-472


1/8/2022
3022
809
-2213


1/9/2022
1047
1075
28


1/10/2022
1242
1805
563


1/11/2022
2765
2537
-228


1/12/2022
2383
2041
-342


1/13/2022
3835
2181
-1654


....
....
.....
....



I have used LSTM model with several layers, including LSTM and Dense layers, and the model is trained on the above data. After training, the model's predictions are plotted against the actual values to visualize the performance. The ARIMA model is used to calculate the error of the LSTM's predictions. These error estimates are subsequently used to adjust the LSTM predictions, resulting in a final, corrected output.
I am using the following LSTM model code:
def LSTM(train, n: int, number_nodes, learning_rate, epochs, batch_size):
middle_data, target_data = apply_transform(train, n)

# Define the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n, 1)),  
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(number_nodes),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=number_nodes, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=number_nodes, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate),
    metrics=["mean_absolute_error"]
)

# Print shapes and model summary
print(f"middle_data shape: {middle_data.shape}")
print(f"target_data shape: {target_data.shape}")
print(f"LSTM input shape: {model.input_shape}")

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    middle_data, target_data,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    verbose=0
)

# Predict and flatten the results
full_predictions = model.predict(middle_data).flatten()

return model, history, full_predictions

Input:
train: A pandas Series or numpy array containing the time series training data.
n=10: An integer defining the number of lagged data points to use as input for the LSTM model.
number_nodes=50: The number of neurons in each LSTM and Dense layer of the neural network.
learning_rate=0.001: The learning rate for the optimizer during training.
epochs=100: The number of epochs to train the model.
batch_size=32: The number of samples per gradient update during training.
def Parameter_calculation(data):
  finding = auto_arima(data,trace = True)
  plot_acf(data,lags = lag)
  address = Output_address + "ACF" +".jpg"
  plt.savefig(address)
  plot_pacf(data,lags = lag)
  address = Output_address + "PACF" +".jpg"
  plt.savefig(address)
  ord = finding.order
  return ord

def ARIMA_Model(train,len_test,ord):
  model = ARIMA(train, order = ord)
  model = model.fit()
  predictions = model.predict(start = len(train),end = len(train) + len_test ,type='levels')
  full_predictions = model.predict(start = 0,end = len(train)-1,type='levels')
  return model,predictions,full_predictions

However the final prediction is still not very good. There is large deviations between the actual and predicted values. For more detail, check this output file : output
Also some of the visualizations are :







Where did the process go wrong? Why the predicted outputs are nowhere near what one would expect?

What sort of analysis have you done yourself on the data and what sort of patterns can you spot? I don't see any patterns in the data based on the plots you've shown, but try to create features that help the model learn the patterns in the data (if there are any).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question pertains to market forecasts, but the answer may be useful in your case as well.
